# CSS: div with display:table; within a list element no auto height?

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I have an unordered list `ul li` where each li is floated but has a height value due to setting `overflow:hidden;` to the list-item.

So when hovering the element in the webinspector the list-item clearly has a height value of 288px.

Within each `li` i also have a `div.caption` with the following attributes:

```css
.caption {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 101%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.6);
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<li>
  <a href="#"><img src="#"></a>
  <div class="caption">some more elements in here</div>
</li>
```

The height of the list-item as mentioned above is automatic due to the height of the image within the li. (the webinspector clearly shows that the list-item has a height)

However my `.caption` div within the li is not automatically as high as the parent. I want the `div.caption` to be 100% as high as the list item.

What can I do here?

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/rgwcL8qt/1/ The overlay should always cover the entire image.

Comment: Put it in js fiddle..its easy to understand..

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rgwcL8qt/1/ The overlay should always cover the entire image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`div.caption { display: table }` with `div.caption-in { display: table-cell }` within creates a new block formatting context.

Changing to `div.caption { display: block; }` should solve your problem.

EDIT: Should you need to center the content inside the caption div then you ought to take a different approach:

```
.caption:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: -0.3em;
}
.caption {
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 101%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.6);
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;       
}
.caption-in {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vmg8jfed/

Comment: However I need to have display: table; because I want my ```.caption-in``` to be centered vertically within the overlay.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
<div style="clear: both"></div>
```

at the end of div containing .caption class.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `div.caption {bottom:0; display:block;}`

[**Fiddel**](http://jsfiddle.net/rgwcL8qt/2/)

Comment: I forgot that it has to be display table in order for the content within the caption to be centered vertically.